# Adding a collapsible header in Sharepoint (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'm having a problem with using jQuery in Sharepoint to add a collapsible header. I am importing jQuery using the Script Editor Web part in Sharepoint, however this is causing problems when I am using more than one  tag.

My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

The code I am surrounding my headers with is

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

When I add the script tags for jQuery in the Script Editor, my page Edit button no longer works. I need to remove the Script part in the page maitenence for it to work again.
How can I implement this in Sharepoint? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Code you provided should work, however If you would like to try other approach you can run this code. It will add scriptlink to web where your page is located (jquery will appear on all pages in this particular web)

**JavaScript code:**

```
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current()
var web = clientContext.get_web();
var UserCustomActions = web.get_userCustomActions();
clientContext.load(UserCustomActions)

var action = UserCustomActions.add();
action.set_location('ScriptLink');
action.set_sequence(5);
action.set_title('jQuery');
action.set_description('jQuery');
action.set_scriptBlock("document.write(\"<script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js'><\\/script>\");");
action.update();

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    alert("done");
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```